# If my application server authenticates access over SPNEGO, what does my app code know about the user?

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, authorization, websphere, single-sign-on

What I am looking to do is authenticate the user at a webpage-level using the application server (WAS)'s authentication against a SPNEGO single sign-on service.

Once the user has been authenticated there, I would then like to be able to limit the actions the user can perform, based on which group they are in, in the Active Directory.

What I don't know is, if the user has been authenticated via SSO, what can the application code itself know about the user and which groups they're in? How does it get that information?

Comment: SPNEGO has nothing to do with it. You could login normally and the effect would be the same. Users groups are read from user registry (most likely AD). To limit actions, you can create security roles in your app, map roles to groups, and then do check in the application via isUserInRole('abc'). That is very short summary. Look for Java EE authentication/authorization articles.

Comment: ah, interesting - so the application doesn't need to know the name of the user to authorise. That's the bit I was missing - how does the app get the username (it doesn't need to). If you write that up as an answer, I'll give you the credit for it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for late response (busy period), I'll try to sum up this in a few days. Just FYI - if you need to access userid of the authenticated user, you can use `request.getRemoteUser()` method. See details here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment by @Gas

SPNEGO has nothing to do with it. You could login normally and the effect would be the same. Users groups are read from user registry (most likely AD). To limit actions, you can create security roles in your app, map roles to groups, and then do check in the application via isUserInRole('abc'). That is very short summary. Look for Java EE authentication/authorization articles.

Therefore, the application doesn't need to know the name of the user to authorise.  you need to access userid of the authenticated user, you can use request.getRemoteUser() method. See details here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser()